# Import multiple files dynamically and pass to LocalizedStrings using 'react-localization'

Tags: reactjs, localization, typescript2.0

I'm using `react-localization` for my localization.
and wanted to fetch JSON files dynamically.
To fetch JSON files i'm using `require.context` but it doesn't load the file contents.

`.ts` file:

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';
var context = require.context('./../assets/i18n/', false);
var files:any={};
context.keys().forEach((filename)=>{
  if(!filename.endsWith(".json")){
     files[filename.substr(2)] = context(filename);
  }
});
const Locale = new LocalizedStrings(files);
export default Locale;
```

`.tsx` file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Locale from '../../libraries/localization';
export const Login: React.FC = () => {
 return (<div className="main-container">
    <p className="section-header">{Locale.login_page.page_title}</p>
   </div>
  )
}
```

I'm able to get json contents dynamically, but typescript giving error in `.tsx` file saying `Property 'login_page' does not exist on type 'LocalizedStringsMethods'`.

Please advise how can I fetch multiple json and assign to `LocalizedStrings`.

Note: When I import json files like `import en from "./../assets/i18n/en.json` and pass it to `LocalizedStrings` as `LocalizedStrings({en})` it works fine. But I don't want to follow this approach. I need to fetch json files at runtime.

Comment: Doesn't my answer bellow cover your use case? If this doesn't work for you or you have any problems implementing it, you can state the problem so I can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes on your implementation. First, you should use [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) to extract just the filename without the extension and use it as a locale key. Second, you want to include `.json` files, not to exclude them, so `if (!filename.endsWith(".json"))` will becode `if (filename.endsWith(".json"))`.

The final code of your `localization.ts` will be:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';

let context = require.context('./../assets/i18n/', false);
let files:any = {};

context.keys().forEach((filename:string) => {
  if (filename.endsWith(".json")) {
     const locale:string = path.basename(filename, '.json');
     const fileContext:string = context(filename);
     files[locale] = fileContext;
  }
});

const Locale = new LocalizedStrings(files);
export default Locale;
```

And that should load all locale json files dynamically.

Comment: Christos, I am also facing the same issue. Is there anyway to pass the file path dynamically in the require.context method or is there any alternate way to do this? Because when I pass the file path  './../assets/i18n/' in the require.context method from variable it doesn't work.